# How do i find the mobile agent in Samsung mobile using C# code?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile, user-agent

I want to connect my mobile agent to some other cloud agent. For that i should find out my mobile agent for making connectivity? In C# code how we can find out or else Is there any other way to find out the agent details.

Comment: do you mean the HTTP user agent?

Comment: Yes...How do we find

Comment: if you are creating an HttpClient in code I don't think it has a user agent by default - this should be trivial to check yourself